# OSX terminal command error

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard

Typed a terminal command to Show Recent on Dock.
Must have made a mistake because now everything's screwed up.
How do I fix the command?

Comment: What is "everything" (i.e. what's screwed up)? What command did you enter?

Answer (score 0):

First option:

You just messed up parts of the Dock configuration. Enter the following in Terminal:

```
 defaults write com.apple.Dock persistent-others -array {}
```

---

Second option (Dock configuration totally broken):

Throw away Library/Preferences/com.apple.Dock.plist in your home directory.

---

After each of these, enter

```
killall Dock
```

in Terminal to restart the Dock (it will maybe take a few seconds to start up again)